# (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[3]' refers to 'groups', which does not refer to a Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

While trying to create my own user model and admin, the test gives the following error.

> : (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'groups', which is not an attribute of 'account.User'.
>   : (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[1]' refers to 'user_permissions', which is not an attribute of 'account.User'.
>   : (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'is_superuser', which does not refer to a Field.
>   : (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[3]' refers to 'groups', which does not refer to a Field.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,username,email,password=None, **extra_fields):
        user=self.model(
            username=username.lower(),
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            **extra_fields)
        #user name is converted into lowercase
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,username,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,email
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.is_staff =True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)


    is_staff =models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects=UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from . import models

# Register your models here.''''

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display=['username','email']


admin.site.register(models.User,UserAdmin)
```

admintest.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

class AdminTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

        self.admin_user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
            username='admin',
            password='123',
            email='fda@gmail.com'
        )
        self.client.force_login(self.admin_user)
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='mantis',
            password='123',
            email='111'
        )

    def test_users_listed(self):
        """Test that users are listed on the user page"""
        url = reverse('admin:core_user_changelist')
        res = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertContains(res, self.user.username)
        self.assertContains(res, self.user.email)
```

Answer (score 19):

You simply need to add `PermissionsMixin` in your `class User(AbstractBaseUser)` such so `User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)`
You can import it with following: `from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin`

Answer (score 0):

if you look at django docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#module-django.contrib.admin

in the Note they said you  need to add your custom fields to fieldsets (for fields to be used in editing users) and to add_fieldsets (for fields to be used when creating a user).

so you need to add these fields to your UserAdmin class

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who come across the same issue, simply import the permission mixin as so: `from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin` and sub-class it with your custom user model (along side the `AbstractBaseUser` class).

Also, there's no need to include email, as the authentication token, in the `REQUIRED_FIELDS` array. This is because the `USERNAME_FIELD` field is already set to email and it's always prompted as required.

Another error you may come across is the `(admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of '<app.CustomUserModel>'`. This is because the `USERNAME_FIELD` in the custom model was re-assigned to use email instead. To fix, add `ordering=("email",)` to the registered custom model fieldsets in *admin.py*.

Answer (score 0):

There is something to note before doing anything: as in my case, you have to make sure there is no method in your model with the same name as the fields which throw `E116`. (Python, right?)

In this example, make sure you don't have any method named `is_superuser` and `groups` in your model.